# Query a single element from a dictionary-like column in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgresSQL table that looks as follows:

```
id             order_id   products
[PK] integer   integer    character varying
1              123        {"type": "foo", "counts": 2}
2              456        {"type": "foobar", "counts": 4}
3              789        {"type": "foo", "counts": 1}
4              678        {"type": "baz", "counts": 3}
```

I would like to query for only where `type = foo`.

In another query, I've successfully used the following:

```
SELECT 
    table_a.data::json->>'type' prod_type,
    
FROM table.a
```

But, this only works because the `data` column is JSON type.

How would I index into the `products` column such that I only return `type = foo`?

```
1              123        {"type": "foo", "counts": 2}
3              789        {"type": "foo", "counts": 1}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE products::json->>'type' = 'foo';
```

Sample Output:

[image]